# how to understand whether I paid already or not for In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am making an app where there are books and books have audio and video services.

Client want In-App Purchase for the app.

Below is how In-App will work.

If user want to buy the book, user will buy the book and once transaction is completed, automatically zip file will get downloaded (from my server where I am adding images, video, audio for book).

Once I have zip, I am un-zipping it once download is completed.

For me the question is how can I identify whether user xyz purchased the book before or not.

e.g. Today User A paid for Book B. How can I get info that User A have purchased book?

If I could have user registration system, I could have identified user by userid of my system.

Some say, save the book id in NSUserDefaults, but concern is if I delete the app and install again, I should download the Book B for free.

I just want to know, how can I keep the track of which user downloaded which book.

***I am making app for iOS 6 and 7 both***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Your app starts the process by calling the restoreCompletedTransactions method of SKPaymentQueue. This sends a request to the App Store to restore all of your app’s completed transactions. If your app sets a value for the applicationUsername property of its payment requests, as described in “Detecting Irregular Activity,” use the restoreCompletedTransactionsWithApplicationUsername: method to provide the same information when restoring transactions.
The App Store generates a new transaction for each transaction that was previously completed. The restored transaction has a reference to the original transaction: instances of SKPaymentTransaction have a originalTransaction property, and the entries in the receipt have an Original Transaction Identifier field.
Your transaction queue observer is called with a status of SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored for each restored transaction, as described in “Waiting for the App Store to Process Transactions.” The action you take at this point depends on the design of your app.

- If your app uses the app receipt and doesn’t have Apple-hosted
  content, this code isn’t needed because your app doesn’t restore
  completed transactions. Finish any restored transactions immediately.
- If your app uses the app receipt and has Apple-hosted content, let
  the user select which products to restore before starting the
  restoration process. During restoration, re-download the
  user-selected content and finish any other transactions immediately

.

```
NSMutableArray *productIDsToRestore = <# From the user #>;
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = <# Current transaction #>;

if ([productIDsToRestore containsObject:transaction.transactionIdentifier]) {
    // Re-download the Apple-hosted content, then finish the transaction
    // and remove the product identifier from the array of product IDs.
} else {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9)

Comment: Purchase restore has been a feature of in-app purchasing since it was released.

Comment: @Paulw11 : ohhk... this sounds goood... just to confirm, let's say I already paid for Book B.. now I delete app and install again... now I try to pay for Book B... Will Apple reply that you have already paid for this book? If Yes, I think I can manage what I want...

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is just like deleting a paid app from your iPad/iPhone. When you try and purchase it again, Apple lets you download it for free

Comment: @brian : But productIDsToRestore is what I will manage in my app.. right? If I delete the app, productIDsToRestore will not have anything...

Comment: @Paulw11 : Ohhk... I am not downloading anything from Apple.. all download is from my server... Apple is just for payment...

Comment: Yes, that was just an example of how the restoration/purchase process works. Apple provides your app with the receipt for the previous purchase - it is up to you to provide the content again

Comment: @Farhim Parker: If you need to support versions of iOS earlier than iOS 7, where the app receipt isn’t available, restore completed transactions instead.

Comment: If this helped you out please put it as answered.